# Why should I use Ansible if I can use image to deploy a system

Tags: ansible, amazon-ami

I can use two ways to Create a new system, or re-create a system upon failure:

1. Always deploy a system using Ansible playbook. the drawback is 1) slow; 2) and the deployment may fail because the package which should be downloaded from open-source repository have been changed/removed sometimes.
2. Temporarily launch a new EC2 and deploy the EC2 using linux command (it is much faster than writing infra-as-code using Ansible); create an AMI image from the EC2; and later on we always use the AMI to create or recreate systems.

I feel 2. is faster and easer, then why we ever need Ansible (or Chef/Puppet) at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know why people get upset about this question. I think it's a fair question to ask. Here are my thoughts and things that I want to point out. Feel free to discuss this in the comments section.

> Ansible is slow

Yes, I agree. If you deploy a large and complex system, it can easily take Ansible playbooks dozens of minutes if not hours to run.

> Ansible playbook may fail because the package which should be downloaded from open-source repository have been changed/removed sometimes

You don't need to worry about this too much. Chances are it rarely happen. Linux package managers pull from these open-source repos frequently everyday. This has never been an issue, and not to mention these repos are very well maintained and a breaking change like this is unlikely. So I don't think this should count as an Ansible drawback.

> Managing AMIs is faster and easier

This is only true in a small scale. If you only have serval dependencies in your environment, it's probably not worthwhile to write everything in IaC and maintain them in version control. However, as systems grows, more complexity needs to be added. You will quick find the IaC approach handy. It allows all changes to the infrastructure to be recorded in the SCM. It enables different developers to work on same infrastructure in parallel etc etc. I can probably tell you a thousand advantages of IaC compared to doing it by hand in AMI. Again, this all depends on your scale. The best approach is the one that fits your need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @jellycsc. Each time when you add new feature, you should add it in ansible, deploy the updated ansible playbook to a temporary launched EC2, and then bake a new AMI from the EC2, so that whenever you launch a new EC2 for actual use, you launch it from the baked AMI instead of deploying it from Ansible right?

Comment: @user389955 You don't need a temporary AMI in the middle, you just run playbooks on EC2's directly.

Comment: at jellycsc: yes we can deploy ec2 using Ansible, but e.g. you have an EC2 as web server and web server is down or need to scale so auto-scaling requires that a new EC2 to be launched and deployed ASAP to reduce downtime. in this case I believe we should launch a new EC2 using AMI, not ansible which is slow.

Comment: @user389955 yeah, i agree. Or you can use AWS image builder to bake an AMI.